# How do I set specific columns in a DataGridView to 0 if it is blank?

Tags: c#, datagridview, null

In this example I am looping through each cell individually. 
However, I have a name column and another optional column which I want to avoid. So I'd rather want to loop through a specific set of columns without the optional one instead but I'm not sure how.

This is how I did the thorough sweep:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVExcel.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (row.Cells[i].Value == null || row.Cells[i].Value == DBNull.Value ||
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[i].Value.ToString()))
        {
            row.Cells[i].Value = 0;
            //DGVExcel.RefreshEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have already done this than what you want?

Comment: I want to go by columns rather than iterating through the whole datagridview cell collection. I believe I wrote it above.

Comment: what do you mean with "another optional column I want to avoid" ?

Comment: @MongZhu, your example seems to be correct, I'll test it out. What I meant was it's merely similar to the name column, which is optional and can be left blank instead of turning it to zero with this loop we've written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I have a name column [...] so I'd rather'd loop through specific columns instead

If I understand you correctly you could get the index of the column and you can skip one for-loop:

```
int colindex = DGVExcel.Columns["SpecificColumnName"].Index;

foreach (var row in DGVExcel.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[colindex].Value == null || row.Cells[colindex].Value == DBNull.Value ||
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[colindex].Value.ToString()))
    {
        row.Cells[colindex].Value = 0;
        //DGVExcel.RefreshEdit();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

> Is there a way to list the excluded columns instead of the included ones, because listing each one would be messy

In this case I would leave it with 2 for-loops. Basically you could save all the names in a List and check whether it contains the name of the current column and if it doesn't then you can do your `0` replacement.

```
List<string> ExcludedColumnsList = new List<string> { "ExcludedColumnName_1", "ExcludedColumnName_2" };           

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVExcel.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!ExcludedColumnsList.Contains(DGVExcel.Columns[i].Name))
        {
            if (row.Cells[i].Value == null || row.Cells[i].Value == DBNull.Value ||
                    String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[i].Value.ToString()))
            {
                row.Cells[i].Value = 0;
                //DGVExcel.RefreshEdit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another option could also be to use linq. Get all indices except the excluded columns and foreach only through those:

```
List<string> ExcludedColumnsList = new List<string> { "ExcludedColumnName_1", "ExcludedColumnName_2" }; 
List<int> indexList = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
            .Where(x => !ExcludedColumnsList.Contains(x.Name))
            .Select(x => x.Index).ToList();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVExcel.Rows)
{
    foreach (int i in indexList)
    { 
        if (row.Cells[i].Value == null || row.Cells[i].Value == DBNull.Value ||
                String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[i].Value.ToString()))
        {
            row.Cells[i].Value = 0;
            //DGVExcel.RefreshEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, now that I think about this, it seems that I would have 20 columns to loop through and only 2 columns excluded. Is there a way to list the excluded columns instead of the included ones, because listing each one would be messy.

Comment: @Arvayne Yes there is. You are left with your 2 for-loops and you can choose whether you want to use linq or an additional if-clause, have a look on my edit

Comment: The list worked perfectly! and in addition to that, I kind of understand how to use lists correctly now.